# Wrong assignment effect with std::vector<const char *>?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, char

The buggy code is below:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
void foo(const std::vector<double> & in) {
  std::vector<const char *> v(5);
  size_t indx = 0; 
  for(auto & tmp : in) {
    auto temp = std::to_string(tmp);
    v[indx] = temp.c_str();
    std::cout << "right: "<< v[indx] << std::endl;
    indx += 1; 
  }
  std::cout << "wrong: " << v[0] << std::endl;
  std::cout << "wrong: " << v[1] << std::endl;
  std::cout << "wrong: " << v[2] << std::endl;
  std::cout << "wrong: " << v[3] << std::endl;
  std::cout << "wrong: " << v[4] << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::vector<double> tmp = {0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05};
  foo(tmp);
  return 0; 
}
```

I compile the code, and in the `for-loop`, the print is right but print wrong outside, what is the problem here?

Comment: Undefined behaviour. You are storing dangling pointers. The objects they point to cease to exist immediately.

Comment: it is still wrong. `temp` also goes out of scope at the end of the block and leaves the stored `const char*` pointing to nowhere

Answer (score 1):

the fault is that `std::to_string(tmp)` creates a temporary object that is destroyed immediately after the semicolon. so the c_str() pointer becomes invalid.

why not using `std::vector<std::string>` to store your strings?

```
std::vector<std::string> v(5);
size_t indx = 0; 
for(auto & tmp : in) {
  v[indx] = std::to_string(tmp);
  std::cout << "right: "<< v[indx] << std::endl;
  indx += 1; 
}
```

Comment: in fact, the OP moves the `std::to_string` to a variable, namely `temp`. So it is not being destroyed at the semicolon but after the `temp` goes out of scope.

Comment: @BrunoFerreira he changed the code. at fist he assigned the output directly without use of `temp`

Answer (score 1):

`std::string::c_str()` does not give you pointers to character arrays that live forever; it gives you pointers to character arrays that live until the `std::to_string(tmp)` dies, which is immediately.

Attempting to access those non-existent character arrays afterwards is undefined.

Use a `std::vector<std::string>` for great success.